# The directory name is invalid for my temporary folder error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to write a nested try-except statement that opens .zip, .gz, and .tar folder, and also regular. txt files. I am downloading these files from the internet, and extract them to a temporary folder. My code works for the .zip, .gz, and .tar folders, but it says my directory name is invalid for the regular .txt files I'm trying to extract to the temporary folder. Here is my code.

```
def function(file_download_url):

   urllib.request.urlopen(file_download_url) #download the zipped file
   dirpath = tempfile.mkdtemp() #Generate a temporary directory 


   #Download the URL as an temporary file that has to be deleted later on
   with urllib.request.urlopen(file_download_url) as response:
      with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, tmp_file)

   print(tmp_file.name) #To display the name of the temporary file created

   #Try-Except statement that extracts compressed files to a temporary directory generated
   try:
       #If it's a .zip file
       with ZipFile(tmp_file.name) as my_zip_file: #Open up the downloaded zipped file
           my_zip_file.extractall(dirpath) #extract the support bundle to the temporary directory created 
           path = dirpath #Make the temporary directory the path for searching
   except:
       try:
           #If it's a .gz or .tar file 
           with tarfile.open(tmp_file.name) as tar:
               tar.extractall(dirpath)
               path = dirpath
               print(path)
       except:
           #If it's just a .txt or .log file 
           source = tmp_file.name
           dest = dirpath

           files = os.listdir(source) #Here is where the error "The directory name is invalid" occurs 

           for f in files:
               shutil.move(source, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem line is `files = os.listdir(source)`, you cannot perform a `listdir` 
operation on a single file. You should instead skip right to the `move` operation:

```
...
except:
    #If it's just a .txt or .log file 
    source = tmp_file.name
    dest = dirpath

    shutil.move(source, dest)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the file is being successfully moved into that directory using this method. Any idea why that is? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm getting "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:"